# Is a request for the .js files still made if a browser has JavaScript disabled?

Tags: lazy-loading, javascript

When a browser has JavaScript disabled, is the request for the .js files still made to the server (ie the files still end up downloaded on the client, but not parsed) ?

The reason I'm asking is to see if it's worth implementing lazy-loading JavaScript files as to prevent the browser from requesting them if JavaScript is disabled; ie only having a small file that does the lazy-loading which then loads the larger files, so that the large files are not requested if JavaScript is disabled in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't.